# Can I build a strong knight with Deserter if the victim removes a mighty knight?

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

I already have all of my basic and mighty knights on the board. I played the *Deserter* Politics Progress Card to one of my opponents, and they chose to remove a mighty knight.

It only says in the Almanac,

> If he chooses a knight that you do not have available (for example, if he removes a “strong” knight and both of your “strong” knights are already on the board), you may place a basic knight instead.

But I figured since the strong knights have a lower rank than the mighty ones (which is the type of knight my opponent removed), I can place it on the board.

Am I allowed to build the strong knight instead of a basic knight, because it is a lower rank than the knight removed?

Should I have promoted my basic knights first to have at least one on my supply, prior to using the *Deserter* card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The rules say you may build a mighty knight, a basic knight if you have no mighty knights available, or nothing at all if you have neither mighty knights nor basic knights.